# Second attempt at a Blackjack game

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, game, playing-cards

I posted yesterday about my [first attempt at a Blackjack game](/q/92586/9357). After I received much helpful advice I tried my best to fix up my code. I was wondering what you would think about round two!

Edit: I also wanted to implement the ability to split a hand if you have two of the same card. My User class already has a split method that adds another hand; what do you think would be the best way to go about adding this feature?

**Card**

```
package Blackjack;

class Card {
private final int rank;
private final int suit;
private static String[] ranks = { "Joker", "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four",
        "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen",
        "King" };
private static String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };

Card(int suit, int values) {
    this.rank = values;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public String toString() {
    return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public int getValue() {
    int value=0;
    if (rank > 10) {
        value = 10;
    } else if (rank == 1) {
        value = 11;
    } else {
        value = rank;
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

**Deck**

```
package Blackjack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

class Deck {
private ArrayList<Card> deck;

Deck() {
    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
            deck.add(new Card(i, j));
        }
    }
}

public void shuffle() {
    Random random = new Random();
    Card temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        int index1 = random.nextInt(deck.size() - 1);
        int index2 = random.nextInt(deck.size() - 1);
        temp = deck.get(index2);
        deck.set(index2, deck.get(index1));
        deck.set(index1, temp);
    }
}

public Card drawCard() {
    return deck.remove(0);
}
}
```

**Hand**

```
package Blackjack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Hand {
private ArrayList<Card> hand;
private int handValue;
private int aceCounter;

Hand(Deck deck) {
    hand = new ArrayList<>();
    aceCounter = 0;
    handValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        hand.add(deck.drawCard());
    }
    Card[] aHand = new Card[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    for (int i = 0; i < aHand.length; i++) {
        handValue += aHand[i].getValue();
        if (aHand[i].getValue() == 11) {
            aceCounter++;
        }
        while (aceCounter > 0 && handValue > 21) {
            handValue -= 10;
            aceCounter--;
        }
    }
}

public void Hit(Deck deck) {
    hand.add(deck.drawCard());
    Card[] aHand = new Card[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    handValue = 0;
    aceCounter=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aHand.length; i++) {
        handValue += aHand[i].getValue();
        if (aHand[i].getValue() == 11) {
            aceCounter++;
        }
        while (aceCounter > 0 && handValue > 21) {
            handValue -= 10;
            aceCounter--;
        }
    }
}

public int getHandSize() {
    return hand.size();
}

public int getHandValue() {
    return handValue;
}

public Card getCard(int cardnum) {
    Card[] aHand = new Card[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    return aHand[cardnum-1];
}

public String toString(){
    String hands ="";
    Card[] aHand = new Card[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    for(int i=0; i<aHand.length-1; i++) {
        hands = hands + aHand[i].toString() + ", ";
    }
    hands = hands + aHand[aHand.length-1].toString();
    return hands;
}   
}
```

**Player**

```
package Blackjack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Player {
ArrayList<Hand> hand;

Player() {
    hand = new ArrayList<Hand>();
}

public boolean hasBlackJack(int handnum) {
    Hand[] aHand = new Hand[] {};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    return (aHand[handnum-1].getHandSize() == 2 && aHand[handnum-1].getHandValue() == 21);
}

public boolean hasBusted() {
    Hand[] aHand = new Hand[] {};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    return (aHand[0].getHandValue() > 21);
}

public Hand getHand(int handnum) {
    Hand[] aHand = new Hand[] {};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    return aHand[handnum-1];
}

public void getNewHand(Deck deck) {
    hand.clear();
    Hand myHand = new Hand(deck);
    hand.add(myHand);
}
}
```

**User**

```
package Blackjack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class User extends Player {
private int cash;
private int bet;
private String name;

User() {
}

public int getCash() {
    return cash;
}

public int getBet() {
    return bet;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setCash(int money) {
    cash = money;
}

public void setBet(int money) {
    bet = money;
}

public void setName(String username) {
    name = username;
}

public void split(Deck deck) {
    Hand hand2 = new Hand(deck);
    hand.add(hand2);
}

public void doubleDown() {
    cash=cash-bet;
    bet=2*bet;
}

public void win() {
    cash=cash+2*bet;
}
public void push() {
    cash=cash+bet;
}
public void blackJack() {
    cash=cash+3*bet;
}

public boolean hasSplit() {
    return hand.size()==2;
}

public boolean hasFiveCardTrick(int handnum) {
    Hand[] aHand = new Hand[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    Hand myHand = aHand[handnum-1];
    return(myHand.getHandSize()==5 && myHand.getHandValue()<21);
}

}
```

**Dealer**

```
package Blackjack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Dealer extends Player {

Dealer() {
}

public void showFirstCard() {
    Card[] firstCard = new Card[] {};
    firstCard = hand.toArray(firstCard);
    System.out.println("[" + firstCard[0] + "]");
}

public boolean wantsToHit() {
    Hand[] aHand = new Hand[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    return aHand[0].getHandValue()<17;
}

public void showHand() {
    System.out.println(hand);
}

public void takeTurn(Deck deck) {
    Hand[] aHand = new Hand[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    while (wantsToHit()) {
        System.out.println("The dealer hits.");
        aHand[0].Hit(deck);
        if (hasBusted()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The dealer stands.");
}
}
```

**Input**

```
package Blackjack;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Input {
private Output outputter;
Input(Output outputs) {
    outputs = outputter;
}

public String getName() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    return name;
}

public int getCash() {
    Scanner money = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cash = money.nextInt();
    return cash;
}

public int getBet(int cash) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bet = sc.nextInt();
        while (bet > cash) {
            outputter.cannotBet();
            outputter.askBet();
            bet=sc.nextInt();
        }
    return bet;
}

public boolean choiceIsYes() {
    Scanner doubledown = new Scanner(System.in);
    String doubled = doubledown.nextLine();
    while (!isyesorno(doubled)) {
        outputter.yesOrNo();
        doubled = doubledown.nextLine();
    }
    return doubled.equals("yes");
}

public boolean isyesorno(String answer) {
    return (answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("no"));
}

public boolean choiceisHit() {
    Scanner hitter = new Scanner(System.in);
    String hit = hitter.nextLine();
    while(!ishitorstand(hit)) {
        outputter.yesOrNo();
        hit = hitter.nextLine();
    }
    return hit.equals("hit");
}

public boolean ishitorstand(String hit) {
    return (hit.equals("hit") || hit.equals("stand"));
}

}
```

**Output**

```
package Blackjack;

class Output {

Output(){
}

public void askName() {
    System.out.println("Hi! What is your name?");
}

public void greeting(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello, "+name+", let's play some Blackjack!");
}

public void askCash() {
    System.out.println("How much cash do you want to start with?");
}

public void tellCashStart(int cash) {
    System.out.println("You start with cash: "+cash);
}

public void showCash(int cash) {
    System.out.println("Cash: "+cash);
}

public void cannotBet() {
    System.out.println("You cannot bet more money than you have!");
}

public void askBet() {
    System.out.println("How much do you wish to bet?");
}

public void showBet(int bet) {
    System.out.println("Money on the table: " + bet);
}

public void showHand(User user) {
    System.out.println("Here is your hand: ");
    System.out.println(user.getHand(1));
}

public void showDealerFirstCard(Dealer dealer) {
    System.out.println("The dealer is showing:");
    Hand hand = dealer.getHand(1);
    System.out.println(hand.getCard(1));
}

public void showDealerHand(Dealer dealer) {
    System.out.println("Here is the dealer's hand:");
    System.out.println(dealer.getHand(1));
}

public void askDoubleDown() {
    System.out.println("Would you like to double down?");
}

public void yesOrNo() {
    System.out.println("Please answer yes or no.");
}

public void hasDoubledDown() {
    System.out.println("You have opted to double down!");
}

public void insurance() {
    System.out.println("The dealer is showing ace! Would you like insurance?");
}

public void hasInsurance() {
    System.out.println("You have opted for insurance!");
}

public void split() {
    System.out.println("You have two of the same card- would you like to split?");
}

public void hasSplit() {
    System.out.println("You have opted to split!");
}

public void splitHands(User user) {
    System.out.println("Here are your hands:");
    System.out.println(user.getHand(1));
    System.out.println(user.getHand(2));
}

public void dealerBlackJack() {
    System.out.println("The dealer has Blackjack!");
}

public void userBlackJack() {
    System.out.println("You have BlackJack!");
    System.out.println("You win 2x your money back!");
}

public void win() {
    System.out.println("Congratulations, you win!");
}

public void lose() {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
}

public void push() {
    System.out.println("It's a push!");
    System.out.println("You get your money back.");
}

public void hitOrStand() {
    System.out.println("Would you like to hit or stand?");
}

public void enterHitorStand() {
    System.out.println("Please enter hit or stand.");
}

public void playAgain() {
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
}

public void cashTotal(int cash) {
    System.out.println("Your cash total is: "+cash);
    System.out.println("Enjoy your winnings!");
}

public void cashTotalZero(int cash) {
    System.out.println("Your total cash is: "+cash);
    System.out.println("You ran out of cash!");
}

public void hasFiveCardTrick() {
    System.out.println("You have a five card trick!");
}

public void winInsurance() {
    System.out.println("The dealer does have Blackjack!");
    System.out.println("You have won your insurance.");
}

public void loseInsurance() {
    System.out.println("Sorry, the dealer does not have Blackjack.");
    System.out.println("You have lost your insurance");
}

public void busted() {
    System.out.println("You busted!");
}

public void dealerBusted() {
    System.out.println("The dealer busted!");
}
}
```

**BlackJack Game**

```
package Blackjack;

public class BlackJackGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Output output = new Output();
    Input input = new Input(output);
    output.askName();
    output.greeting(input.getName());
    output.askCash();
    User user = new User();
    Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
    user.setCash(input.getCash());
    while (user.getCash() > 0) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();
        user.getNewHand(deck);
        dealer.getNewHand(deck);
        output.showCash(user.getCash());
        output.askBet();
        user.setBet(input.getBet(user.getCash()));
        user.setCash(user.getCash() - user.getBet());
        output.showCash(user.getCash());
        output.showBet(user.getBet());
        output.showHand(user);
        output.showDealerFirstCard(dealer);
        if (dealer.getHand(1).getCard(1).getRank() == 1) {
            output.insurance();
            if (input.choiceIsYes()) {
                if (dealer.hasBlackJack(1)) {
                    output.winInsurance();
                    user.win();
                    output.showCash(user.getCash());
                } else {
                    output.loseInsurance();
                    output.showCash(user.getCash());
                }
            }
        }
        if (user.hasBlackJack(1) && dealer.hasBlackJack(1)) {
            output.userBlackJack();
            output.dealerBlackJack();
            output.push();
            user.push();
        } else if (user.hasBlackJack(1)) {
            user.blackJack();
            output.userBlackJack();
            output.win();
        } else if (dealer.hasBlackJack(1)) {
            output.dealerBlackJack();
            output.lose();
        } else {
            if (2 * user.getBet() < user.getCash()) {
                output.askDoubleDown();
                if (input.choiceIsYes()) {
                    user.doubleDown();
                    output.showCash(user.getCash());
                    output.showBet(user.getBet());
                }
            }
            output.hitOrStand();
            while (input.choiceisHit()) {
                user.getHand(1).Hit(deck);
                output.showHand(user);
                output.hitOrStand();
                if (user.hasBusted()) {
                    output.busted();
                    output.lose();
                    break;
                }
                if (user.hasFiveCardTrick(1)) {
                    output.hasFiveCardTrick();
                    output.win();
                    user.win();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!user.hasBusted()) {
                dealer.takeTurn(deck);
                output.showDealerHand(dealer);
                if (dealer.hasBusted()) {
                    output.dealerBusted();
                    output.win();
                    user.win();
                } else {
                    if ((21 - user.getHand(1).getHandValue()) < (21 - dealer
                            .getHand(1).getHandValue())) {
                        output.win();
                        user.win();
                    }
                    if ((21 - user.getHand(1).getHandValue()) == (21 - dealer
                            .getHand(1).getHandValue())) {
                        output.push();
                        user.push();
                    }
                    if ((21 - user.getHand(1).getHandValue()) > (21 - dealer
                            .getHand(1).getHandValue())) {
                        output.lose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        output.showCash(user.getCash());
        output.playAgain();
        if (!input.choiceIsYes()) {
            break;
        }

    }
    if (user.getCash() == 0) {
        output.cashTotalZero(user.getCash());
    }
    output.cashTotal(user.getCash());
}
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you summarized the improvements you made.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit better detail what the changes are? Think of the questions "Which, what and why" (currently you only answer 'which'). See http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1066/31562

Comment: okay will do! before I had only a dealer, card, and deck class. My blackjack game class ran the whole game, include printing, taking input, and taking output. The bulk of comments I got were about class organization so I added the classes player, user, input, and output and made it so my blackjack game class didn't violate the single functionality rule and only ran the game. I also reformatted it to look like typical java format.

Comment: I am asking for another review for feedback on how i did addressing each of the issues my previous version had and for any additional tips users may have for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Structure**

Your structure is a lot better. There are a couple of things I would do differently, but generally it's good.

- a `Hand` doesn't really need a deck, just a card (it makes more logical sense, I think).
- I think you have many `Hand`s in `Player` because of splitting? That makes sense. But your `hasBlackJack` etc methods only handle the first hand, so that makes it useless. I would probably move those check methods directly into `Hand`.
- I would let `choiceisHit` return a `Action` enum, which could be `Hit`, `Stay`, `Split`, etc. This will make it a lot easier to add other actions later on (double, split, surrender, etc).
- your main method is too long, it's really hard to find the pieces you are interested in, which will make it really hard to change it or extend it. I would at least create a method for one round of blackjack and one method for the setup at the beginning.

**Arrays and Lists**

I noted this last time, but as you still convert lists to arrays, I think maybe you don't know how to handle lists on their own?

Generally - if you don't have a good reason to do it differently-, you should stick with the collection you have. If it's an array, handle the array. If it's a list, handle the list.

Eg this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    hand.add(deck.drawCard());
}
Card[] aHand = new Card[]{};
aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
for (int i = 0; i < aHand.length; i++) {
    handValue += aHand[i].getValue();
    if (aHand[i].getValue() == 11) {
        aceCounter++;
    }
    while (aceCounter > 0 && handValue > 21) {
        handValue -= 10;
        aceCounter--;
    }
}
```

Can be rewritten without the array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    hand.add(deck.drawCard());
}
for (Card card : hand) {
    handValue += card.getValue();
    if (card.getValue() == 11) {
        aceCounter++;
    }
    while (aceCounter > 0 && handValue > 21) {
        handValue -= 10;
        aceCounter--;
    }
}
```

Personally, I would handle the value counting in `getHandValue` on the fly, to avoid the trouble with the aces and the duplication in `Hand` and `Hit` (you could also avoid this by just calling `Hit` twice in your constructor).

You do the same conversion from list to array in a couple of other places as well. Eg this:

```
public Card getCard(int cardnum) {
    Card[] aHand = new Card[]{};
    aHand = hand.toArray(aHand);
    return aHand[cardnum-1];
}
```

could be this:

```
public Card getCard(int cardnum) {
    return hand.get(cardnum);
}
```

Same in `toString`, `hasBlackJack`, `hasBusted`, etc.

**Naming**

- your naming isn't always consistent. Eg `getNewHand` returns nothing, while `getHand` returns a hand. `getNewHand` should probably be something like `dealHand`.
- `choiceIsYes` retrieves user input, while `isyesorno` does not. I would use the `getX` naming pattern you used for the other methods here.
- always use camelCase (see eg `ishitorstand`).
- again, methods should start with a lower-case character, so they are not confused with classes/constructors.

**Misc**

- in `drawCard` you do not check if there is still a card left, which will lead to a nullpointer exception when there aren't.
- you still have your `shuffle` method which can be replaced by `Collections.shuffle(deck);`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely clean up the main method and fix all the method and variable names. You're right- i do not really know how to handle lists on their own very well.

Comment: I am pretty unfamiliar with this syntax: for (Card card : hand). I also didn't know how to do the Collections.shuffle thing but i will replace my shuffle method with it now. One other thing I am unfamiliar with that you used in your response is the action enums. I will look into those. Once again, thank you for the very detailed response.

Comment: @Jared [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are basically classes light (action enums aren't a thing, I just meant an enum called `Action`). `for (Card card : hand) { // your code }` is called an enhanced for loop. It is shorthand for `for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++) { Card card = hand.get(i); // your code }`

Comment: ahh. thank you very much for clarification and the link